# Guizero on Pycharm will not start

Tags: python, pycharm, guizero

I was starting my coding journey but hit a wall before even starting.

When I am trying to run a guizero code from pycharm I am getting this error
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'guizero' "

But it works fine If i run it via python command prompt. So with my little knowladge I feel pycharm is not able to see guizero libraries and I have no idea how to make it happen.

So tldr is HALP! Thanks in advance for any response ^^

Answer (score 0):

Well opening an account here made me fluffier eneough to solve my own issue.

For those who experience same just download zip version of guizero. Copy the guizero folder in guizero-master and paste it to  blabla/PyCharm/Blabla/Lib so pycharm can see it as external library ^^